# dotnetcore 2.1 mvc on nginx - routing issues

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core-2.1

I've been working on a dotnetcore 2.1 mvc application to be hosted on ubuntu/nginx. Everything works great on my local (windows) dev environment. Routing works correctly. I've pretty carefully followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1 . However, when I try to publish the application to my configured ubuntu nginx instance it will bring up the main page. However, if I try to go to any other page via it's route it brings up a 404 error. For instance I created a page that should live at /home/success but when i visit that page it says it doesn't exist. If I use curl while logged into the instance and point it to http://localhost:5000/home/success it also brings up a 404 error. Here is the code i'm using.

Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<appsettings>(Configuration.GetSection("appsettings"));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen        80;
root          /var/www/cardnmore-customer/wwwroot;
server_name   ec2-54-149-68-43.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

}

Finally here's the staging URL for the application i'm working on.
http://ec2-54-149-68-43.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I'm hoping this is something painfully obvious, but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out since last night. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So of course right after I post this question, I figure out that restarting the nginx service doesn't reload the application apparently. I had to actually restart my cardnmore-customer.service for it to make my changes take hold. I did a few things before I came here and I suspect one of those things is what worked. The first thing I did was add this to my Configure void in startup.cs

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
```

The other thing I did was update my default conf file so that it had the actual url under server_name (was originally blank)

```
server {
listen        80;
root          /var/www/cardnmore-customer/wwwroot;
server_name   ec2-54-149-68-43.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Anyway, if anyone has anything to add to this please feel free.